# Android Bluetooth Application

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

Hi I'm sort of new to developing on android and have recently started working with the bluetooth API.  I've been able to connect my phone to HC-06 hooked up to my Arduino NANO. However I cannot seem to transfer data correctly.  My goal is to grab the current value from the device and save it to a variable on the app while also displaying it. Here is my code for both the arduino and the app.

Android Studio

```
package com.clipius.clipiusweight;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView myLabel;
    TextView dataLabel;
    EditText myTextbox;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    Thread workerThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    int counter;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getDataB);
        Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendDataB);
        //Button closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
        myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ConnectionCheck);
        dataLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weightValueText);
        //myTextbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightValueText);

        //Open Button
        openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    findBT();
                    openBT();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });

    }



    void findBT()
    {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
        }

        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            {
                if(device.getName().equals("HC-06"))
                {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
    }

    void openBT() throws IOException
    {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        beginListenForData();

        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
    }

    void beginListenForData()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character // old 10

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;


                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            dataLabel.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting Worker Thread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        workerThread.start();
    }

}
```

Arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int sensorPin = A0; 
int sensorValue = 0;
char stringValue[5];

SoftwareSerial BTserial(10, 11); // RX | TX


void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 BTserial.begin(9600);    
}

void loop() {

// Gets the int. value of the sensor
sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);

//conversion to string so AS can read it in.
itoa(sensorValue, stringValue, 10);

// Writes value to console for debugging
Serial.println(stringValue);


      BTserial.print(stringValue); 
      BTserial.print(sensorValue);

           delay(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

For all my Android/Arduino project i use this thread:
(let me know if you need more info, because this method WORKS !!)
Launch the connection Thread in your openButton's OnClick.

Connection Thread (establish stable connection):

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //connectedNotification("DIS");
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        //connectedNotification("Connecting ...");
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
            beginListenForData();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, 1);
                mmSocket.connect();
                beginListenForData();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    //connectedNotification("DIS");
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    //connectedNotification("DIS");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //connectedNotification("DIS");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there maybe what u want are here...Good luck and big hugs from Brasil.

And the author say this " I used to send the buffer from my run method in the connectThread but found that I would sometimes get garbled data with anything but slow data rates. It turns out this was because the buffer was getting full and struggling to keep up. A much better method is to create a string in the run method from the buffer and then send that to the UI thread via the handler.". ok

The link bellow :
https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/android-sendreceive-data-with-arduino-using-bluetooth-part-2/

same stuff and another url bellow :
http://solderer.tv/data-transfer-between-android-and-arduino-via-bluetooth/

Best regards, sir !!